# How to Read Related Data Using LINQ in One-to-Many RS

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, one-to-many

Two models:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? StorageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Storage? Storage { get; set; }
}

public class Storage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StorageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item>? Items { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a table where I could see a storage name for every item. How to achieve that using web api? Is there any LINQ method or I should create some more properties in Item model?

I am getting a JSON possible cycle error if I use this:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Item>>> GetItems()
{
    var item = await _context.Items.Include(c => c.Storage).ToListAsync();

    return item;
}
```

I saw the way to avoid cycle error using

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

But not sure it is a good practice..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good practice is to create additional DTO class which represents result data and build this entity via `Select` or via Automapper's `ProjectTo`.  Then circular references will never appear. Anyway you can add `AsNoTracking()` to the query and EF will not fixup circular reference properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv could you please provide some code examples? I am trying to figure out how to achieve my goal all day already :/

Comment: Try using `AsNoTracking` first. Then read several articles about DTO (Data Transfer Object)

Comment: Still seeking for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603118/how-to-resolve-system-text-json-jsonexception-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detec)